# Generate new variable based on conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

So I have this df with state and year information. My goal is to generate a new variable, **state_year**, so that Alabama in 1982 gets assigned a 1, Alabama in 1983 gets assigned a 2, Alabama in 1984 gets assigned a 3, etc.

When I try the following, I get "TRUE" for the right cases, but I want it to say "1" (and then subsequently 2 for AL in 1983, etc).

```
test <- df %>%
    mutate(state_year = statefip == 1 & year == 1982)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We could group by 'state' and get the unique ids by applying `rleid` on the 'statefip', 'year' (assuming the columns are ordered)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, state_year := rleid(statefip, year), state]
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
    mutate(state_year = str_c(state_fip, year)) %>%
    group_by(state) %>%
    mutate(state_year = match(state_year, unique(state_year))
```

Comment: The dplyr version is exactly what I was looking for. I was unfamiliar with the "unique" code, will learn more about this. Thank you!

Comment: What If I also wanted to try to generate state_year so that each state-year combo has to have a unique code, i.e. no two can have a value of 3. For example, Alabama in 1982 = 1 Alabama in 1983 = 2, Alabama in 1984 = 4, Wyoming  in 1984 = 52, etc. So: 50 states x 36 years = 1,800 values.

Comment: @AMB1274 That was my earlier answer.  You could just do `setDT(df)[, state_year := rleid(stateid, year)]`

Answer (score 1):

For each `state` you can convert year to `factor` and then to `integer` to get a unique number.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(state) %>%
  mutate(state_year = as.integer(factor(year)))
```

If we want to unique number for each state-year combination we can paste `state` and `year` together and convert to `factor` and then `integer`.

```
df %>%
  mutate(state_year = paste0(state, year), 
         state_year = as.integer(factor(state_year, levels = unique(state_year))))
```